# Win10 Bug causes a character to not type

Tags: windows-10, characters, bug

One of the character letters (the lower case 't') is not working on my laptop.  I thought it was the keyboard, but I tried many, good, working keyboards with this laptop, and they all fail on it, though they work on other PCs.   Moreover, the letter 't' works fine in Virtual Box on the same laptop, running another OS.  And even on the main install of Win10 on my laptop, the 't' works inside dialog boxes, but nowhere else, on any program. (Capital T works everywhere, and I can always copy and paste a 't').  So, what's causing this?   And short of re-installing windws10, are there any fixes??

Answer (score 0):

> One of the character letters (the lower case 't') is not working on my
> laptop. I thought it was the keyboard, but I tried many, good, working
> keyboards with this laptop, and they all fail on it

It does not appear to be a hardware issue (multiple keyboards).

Try repairing Windows.

**One:  DISM and SFC.**

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

**Two: If the above does not work, try a Windows 10 Repair Install.**

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  There are 3 ways to
> proceed, according to the severity of the error.
>
> (1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back
> just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup,
> but generally nothing will be lost.
>
> (2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive.
> Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always
> have a backup, but data is not usually lost.
>
> (3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is
> essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your
> data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged,
> because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally
> easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It
> depends on the precise situation.

Comment: Thank you, I will try these later this week